# 3D Touch actions not working (swift 3)

Tags: iphone, swift3, xcode8, 3dtouch

So, I have managed to get everything hooked up properly. When the short cut actions are pressed, I get the correct Print out in the console. Where do I go from here? I can't figure it out...

This is my code in App Delegate

```
    var quicklaunch: Bool!
    var viewName: String?

   func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    viewName = shortcutItem.type
    quicklaunch = true
    completionHandler(quicklaunch)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if quicklaunch == true {
        quicklaunch = false
        if viewName == "Messages" {
            let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController
            let popUpController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendsVC")
            rootViewController?.present(popUpController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Worked")
        }
    }  
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if quicklaunch == false {
        quicklaunch = true
        if viewName == "Messages" {
            let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController
            let popUpController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendsVC")
            rootViewController?.present(popUpController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Worked")
        }
    }

}
```

How do I get it to pop up to the correct view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `rootViewController` and then present the required `viewController` modally (or push it onto navigation stack if your `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`). Something along the lines of

```
let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController
let popUpController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "???") as! ???
rootViewController.present(popUpController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Replace `???` with corresponding values

**EDIT**

Make a boolean variable in your AppDelegate called `quickLaunch` and a string variable `viewName`. Then update the following two methods

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    viewName = shortcutItem.type
    quickLaunch = true
    completionHandler(quickLaunch)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if quickLaunch == true {
        quickLaunch = false
        //PRESENT YOUR VIEW MODALLY HERE
    }  
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately...this did not work. It still just opens to whatever the app was perviously open too. It doesn't do anything else. Ugh.

Comment: My bad. Please see the updated answer. You have to use `present` instead of `show`

Comment: It is still not working. I have tried using `present` instead of `show`.

Comment: Probably because you are trying to present a `UITabBarController` as a modal pop up. Try it with a `UIViewController`. That is not to say that change the word `UITabBarController` with `UIViewController` but to actually use a controller that IS a `UIViewController`. Also, is the "Worked" message being printed on console?

Comment: Yes, the "Worked" message is being printed and I experience no crash. I just tried to use a UIViewController and the result is the same. The app just opens where it was the I closed it. I noticed that it works if I completly close the app and then use the short cut, but after that, it does not work. Could it have anything to do with a user having to log into my app?

Comment: Oh okay. That makes more sense. See the edited answer

Comment: So I added your following code and its still not working...The application is still only going to the short cut view if I completly close the app first.

Comment: Alright, it is edited. I know I am doing something simply stupid. Haha

Comment: Why do you have the same function in your code twice? Remove the second `performActionFor` method (The one with `@escaping`). Also, add `as UIViewController` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`